# Help with simple SOAP client in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, soap

I have a small SOAP client written in PERL, would someone be able to show me how this could be converted for use in C# instead?

SoapClient:

```
   use SOAP::Lite;
   my $client = SOAP::Lite->new();
   $client->uri('urn:Hello');
   $client->proxy('http://mydomain.com:8001');
   my $som = $client->hello();
   my $output = $som->result;
   print $output . "\n";
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio, or are you doing this all in some other editor?  This makes a great difference, as Visual Studio will do 99.9999% of the work for you, and we'll need to tailor our answers if you're using something else.

Comment: @David Stratton Hi David, I work in Visual Studio 2010 professional

Answer (score 2):

See this page and scroll down to the "Adding the Web Service as a Component" section.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wbhsy70.aspx

The point of the post is that Visual Studio creates the proxy client for you.  This example shows how - not specific to your case, but the contept is the same.  When adding the web reference (or service reference) point it to the url of your servlce.

The above link, by the way, points to the "old" web service references.  In newer versions of hte Framework, you're encouraged to use the "Service Reference" instead.  The link here describes those:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx